# Compatible way to bind to 169.254.169.254?

Tags: linux, docker, redhat, oracle

I have an application which I can't change, running in a docker container on a bare metal server (no cloud environment)

It tries to connect to `169.254.169.254` (fetching IMDSv2 metadata).
This ip / the service is not reachable and the application waits before the request times-out.
During wait, the application does not respond.

I would like to solve this issue by providing a service on this ip.
What's the correct way to do this, ideally without having special privileges for the container?

For the sake of testing, I started a simple webserver and added an internal IP route from `169.254.169.254` to `127.0.0.1` which solved the problem - however, this requires special docker privileges ( `--cap-add NET_ADMIN`).

**Is there a better way to do this?** (e.g. maybe there's a RHEL/Linux service which can bind on this special ip. Binding to 0.0.0.0 did not work)

Comment: Is the app actually hard coded  to reach out to that IP-address, or does it do so by resolving a FQDN? If it's the latter it should be trivial to the override that FQDN and point to  an IP that either returns an immediate `connection refused` or a mock response.

Comment: @Bob - it's probably via IP as that's the address used for retrieving instance metadata in e.g. AWS.

Comment: The application (oracle database btw) hard coded the IP. @shearn89 is right, they do it for detecting a possible cloud environment.